# Sorting a list of strings by number in acending order with multiple decimals

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to sort the following list:

```
2.1.0.0
2.1.1.0
2.1.11.0
2.1.12.0
2.1.13.0
2.1.14.0
2.1.15.0
2.1.2.0
2.1.3.0
2.1.4.0
2.1.5.0
2.1.6.0
2.1.7.0
2.1.8.0
2.1.9.0
```

To achieve the following list:

```
2.1.0.0
2.1.1.0
2.1.2.0
2.1.3.0
2.1.4.0
2.1.5.0
2.1.6.0
2.1.7.0
2.1.8.0
2.1.9.0
2.1.11.0
2.1.12.0
2.1.13.0
2.1.14.0
2.1.15.0
```

I am trying to sort this by what is after the second decimal by that order. I have tried Arrays.sort but it was not successful. Here is my code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NewSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] numbers = { "2.1.0.0", "2.1.1.0", "2.1.11.0", "2.1.12.0",
                "2.1.13.0", "2.1.14.0", "2.1.15.0", "2.1.2.0", "2.1.3.0",
                "2.1.4.0", "2.1.5.0", "2.1.6.0", "2.1.7.0", "2.1.8.0",
                "2.1.9.0" };

        Arrays.sort(numbers);

        for (String number : numbers) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You will have to write your own `Comparator`.

Comment: 2 solutions : pad your numbers with some 0 OR write a custom comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to sort this by what is after the second decimal by that order.

You can write your own [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
enum MyStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1.split("\\.")[2]);
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.split("\\.")[2]);
        return Integer.compare(n1, n2);
    }
}
```

And now:

```
String[] numbers = { "2.1.0.0", "2.1.1.0", "2.1.11.0", "2.1.12.0",
        "2.1.13.0", "2.1.14.0", "2.1.15.0", "2.1.2.0", "2.1.3.0",
        "2.1.4.0", "2.1.5.0", "2.1.6.0", "2.1.7.0", "2.1.8.0",
        "2.1.9.0" };

Arrays.sort(numbers, MyStringComparator.INSTANCE);

for (String number : numbers) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

```
2.1.0.0
2.1.1.0
2.1.2.0
2.1.3.0
2.1.4.0
2.1.5.0
2.1.6.0
2.1.7.0
2.1.8.0
2.1.9.0
2.1.11.0
2.1.12.0
2.1.13.0
2.1.14.0
2.1.15.0
```

I'll leave it to you to incorporate any error-checking mechanism that you may need.

---

In Java 8 it's a lot easier:

```
Arrays.sort(numbers,
            Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("\\.")[2])));
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, I guess you solved a homework exercise there =\

Comment: By the way the `public static void main(String[] args)` looks. Seems like an exercise for an algorithm course. And because I had to solve similar problems in my college time :).

Comment: its for a large project, i just split up the test instance into smaller piece of code to test :)

Comment: @user3767481 ok. Do you need to compare only by the third number after the second dot (.) or you should do this for every number?

Comment: i just need this for a comparison after the second dot, I am having trouble in my class that I have now took this code and dropped it into the large scale project. My error is that it cannot find the symbol compare in Integer.compare even though I have imported the comparator?

Comment: @user3767481 You must be using Java 6 or below, in that case. You can replace `Integer.compare(n1, n2)` with `Integer.valueOf(n1).compareTo(n2)`.

Comment: I think I now understood your previous question before with the every number. I also have use cases were I have strings such as 2.1.9.0-12.14.165 which I also want to incorporate into this sort still by just looking at what is after the second dot, how would I change the comparator to do so?

Comment: @user3767481 "2.1.9.0-12.14.165" should also work with this method.